# Extract urls from text file using regex pattern

Tags: python-3.7

I am trying to extract the urls from the text file

My text file:

> ABCD ABCD.com | 13XYZ@gmail.com | + 1234567890 Page Street No. 7 San Francisco, Ca 94117 Selected Experience Data Scientist Data Innovation Lab @ Capital One (San Francisco, Ca.) 06/15 - Now Lead research team modeling for fraud problem space with class imbalance & adversaries; H2O.ai, GraphLab, \u2019s, Linear Algebra, Graduate Econometrics Personal Projects Beautiful Soup 4 Built a multi-threaded web scraper and search engine with web user interface; Java, MySQL and HTML5/CSS Built resume parsing package which extracts text, finds contact details, and checks for required keywords; Python and Pandas Online Hergertarian.com github.com/xyz linkedin.com/in/xyz abcd.wordpress.com

My Code:

```
re.findall(.(?:(?:https?):\/\/)?(?:www\.)?[a-z-]+\.(?:com|org)(?:\.[a-z]{2,3})?.)
```

Output:

> @gmail.com
>
> Human.com
>
> github.com/
>
> linkedin.com/

Expected Output:

> ABCD.com
>
> 13XYZ@gmail.com
>
> Human.com
>
> github.com/xyz
>
> linkedin.com/in/xyz
>
> abcd.wordpress.com

Can someone please tell me what changes is required here?

Comment: Can't find Human.com in your text. Anyway, I made it work here: https://www.regexpal.com/?fam=111103 I'd suggest you separate E-Mail matching from URI matching and put in additional cases because URLs and E-Mails can be much more complicated. Relevant RFCs: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1738 https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986 https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6530 If you want to do it well consider using libraries.

Comment: Thanks.. It worked perfectly for my problem@MarcDix

Comment: Ok, I'm kinda glad and sad at the same time, because it's not a good, reliable solution but solves your problem. But hey, depends on what you use it for and what happens if it fails / yields false positives. ;-)